DWT in EasyLanguage (Tradestation or Multicharts)
I am trying to implement a code in EasyLanguage, for MODWT and IMODWT, using a rolling window, however when reconstructing the signal I get a different scale. Could you tell me what is wrong with the code?
I am trying to break down 4 levels. I'm using circular convolution and inverting the signal to avoid look-ahead bias.
Inputs:
    Price((H+L)/2),
    Length(64); // Longitud de la serie de precios

Array: 
double hcoeff[4](0), 
double gcoeff[4](0),
double PriceInv[](0),
double PriceInv2[](0),
double W1[](0), 
double W2[](0), 
double W3[](0), 
double W4[](0), 
double V1[](0), 
double V2[](0), 
double V3[](0), 
double V4[](0),
double W1inv[](0),
double W2inv[](0),
double W3inv[](0),
double W4inv[](0),
double V1inv[](0),
double V2inv[](0),
double V3inv[](0),
double V4inv[](0);   

Array_SetMaxIndex(PriceInv, Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(PriceInv2,Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(W1, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(W2, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(W3, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(W4, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(V1, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(V2, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(V3, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(V4, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(W1inv, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(W2inv, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(W3inv, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(W4inv, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(V1inv, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(V2inv, 4*Length) ;
Array_SetMaxIndex(V3inv, 4*Length) ;    
Array_SetMaxIndex(V4inv, 4*Length) ;            
            
Variables: 
idx(0), 
jdx(0), 
sum(0),
sum2(0),
level(0);

// ----- Coeficientes ----
// https://wavelets.pybytes.com/wavelet/db2/
// Daubechies 2 Decomposition low-pass filter           
hcoeff[3] =( 0.4829629131445341) ; // Squareroot(2));
hcoeff[2] =( 0.8365163037378079/Squareroot(2));
hcoeff[1] =(-0.2241438680420134/Squareroot(2));
hcoeff[0] =(-0.1294095225512604/Squareroot(2)); 

// Daubechies 2 Decomposition high-pass filter
gcoeff[3] = (-0.1294095226/Squareroot(2));
gcoeff[2] = (-0.2241438680/Squareroot(2));
gcoeff[1] = (0.8365163037/Squareroot(2));
gcoeff[0] = (-0.4829629131/Squareroot(2));          

// ---- Ventana deslizante invertida
For idx = 0 to Length - 1 Begin
    PriceInv[Length - 1 - idx] = Price[idx];
    PriceInv2[Length - 1 - idx] = Price[idx];
End;


// Realizar convolución circular para Wx (coeficientes de aproximacion) y Vy (coeficientes de detalle)
For level  = 0 to 4 begin // Level nivel de descomposicion
    If level = 0 then begin
        For idx = 0 to Length - 1 Begin
            sum = 0;
            sum2 = 0;
            For jdx = 0 to 3 Begin // 4 coeficientes para db2
                sum = sum + hcoeff[jdx] * PriceInv[Mod(idx - power(2,level) *jdx + Length, Length)];
                sum2 = sum2 + gcoeff[jdx] * PriceInv2[Mod(idx - power(2,level) *jdx + Length, Length)];
            End;
            W1[idx] = sum;
            V1[idx] = sum2;
        End;
    End;

    If level = 1 then begin
        For idx = 0 to Length - 1 Begin
            sum = 0;
            sum2 = 0;
            For jdx = 0 to 3 Begin // 4 coeficientes para db2
                sum = sum + hcoeff[jdx] * W1[Mod(idx - power(2,level) *jdx + Length, Length)];
                sum2 = sum2 + gcoeff[jdx] * V1[Mod(idx - power(2,level) *jdx + Length, Length)];
            End;
            W2[idx] = sum;
            V2[idx] = sum2;
        End;
    End;

    If level = 2 then begin
        For idx = 0 to Length - 1 Begin
            sum = 0;
            sum2 = 0;
            For jdx = 0 to 3 Begin // 4 coeficientes para db2
                sum = sum + hcoeff[jdx] * W2[Mod(idx - power(2,level) *jdx + Length, Length)];
                sum2 = sum2 + gcoeff[jdx] * V2[Mod(idx - power(2,level) *jdx + Length, Length)];
            End;
            W3[idx] = sum;
            V3[idx] = sum2;
        End;
    End;
    
    If level = 3 then begin
        For idx = 0 to Length - 1 Begin
            sum = 0;
            sum2 = 0;
            For jdx = 0 to 3 Begin // 4 coeficientes para db2
                sum = sum + hcoeff[jdx] * W3[Mod(idx - power(2,level) *jdx + Length, Length)];
                sum2 = sum2 + gcoeff[jdx] * V3[Mod(idx - power(2,level) *jdx + Length, Length)];
            End;
            W4[idx] = sum;
            V4[idx] = sum2;
        End;        
    End;
End;

// --- invertimos nuevamente ----
For idx = 0 to Length - 1 Begin
    W1inv[idx] = W1[Length - 1 - idx];
    W2inv[idx] = W2[Length - 1 - idx];
    W3inv[idx] = W3[Length - 1 - idx];
    W4inv[idx] = W4[Length - 1 - idx];
    V1inv[idx] = V1[Length - 1 - idx];
    V2inv[idx] = V2[Length - 1 - idx];
    V3inv[idx] = V3[Length - 1 - idx];
    V4inv[idx] = V4[Length - 1 - idx];
End;

//--- Reconstruccion
// --- Coeficientes de reconstrucción (reverso de los coeficientes de descomposición) ---
Array:
double hcoeff_recon[4](0) ,
double gcoeff_recon[4](0)  ;

// Coeficientes de reconstrucción low-pass (aproximación) y high-pass (detalle) para db2
// Los coeficientes de reconstrucción son diferentes de los de descomposición y se deben aplicar de manera correcta según el proceso inverso.
hcoeff_recon[0] = (0.4829629131 / Squareroot(2)); // Coeficiente de reconstrucción para db2 con escalado
hcoeff_recon[1] = (0.8365163037 / Squareroot(2)); // Coeficiente de reconstrucción para db2 con escalado
hcoeff_recon[2] = (0.2241438680 / Squareroot(2)); // Coeficiente de reconstrucción para db2 con escalado
hcoeff_recon[3] = (-0.1294095226 / Squareroot(2)); // Coeficiente de reconstrucción para db2 con escalado

gcoeff_recon[0] = (-0.1294095226 / Squareroot(2));  // Coeficiente de reconstrucción high-pass para db2 con escalado
gcoeff_recon[1] = (0.2241438680 / Squareroot(2));   // Coeficiente de reconstrucción high-pass para db2 con escalado
gcoeff_recon[2] = (-0.8365163037 / Squareroot(2));  // Coeficiente de reconstrucción high-pass para db2 con escalado
gcoeff_recon[3] = (0.4829629131 / Squareroot(2));   // Coeficiente de reconstrucción high-pass para db2 con escalado

Array:
double ReconstructedSignal[](0);
Array_SetMaxIndex(ReconstructedSignal, Length);

// Inicializar la señal reconstruida a partir de W4inv (aproximación más gruesa)
For idx = 0 to Length - 1 Begin
    ReconstructedSignal[idx] = W4inv[idx];
End;

// Reconstruir hacia arriba aplicando los coeficientes de reconstrucción para cada nivel de detalle
For level = 4 downto 1 Begin
    For idx = 0 to Length - 1 Begin
        sum = 0;
        For jdx = 0 to 3 Begin // 4 coeficientes para db2
            If level = 4 then Begin
                sum = sum + (gcoeff_recon[jdx] * V4inv[Mod(idx + power(2, level - 1) * jdx + Length, Length)]);
                sum = sum + (hcoeff_recon[jdx] * W4inv[Mod(idx + power(2, level - 1) * jdx + Length, Length)]);
            End;
            If level = 3 then Begin
                sum = sum + (gcoeff_recon[jdx] * V3inv[Mod(idx + power(2, level - 1) * jdx + Length, Length)]);
                sum = sum + (hcoeff_recon[jdx] * W3inv[Mod(idx + power(2, level - 1) * jdx + Length, Length)]);
            End;
            If level = 2 then Begin
                sum = sum + (gcoeff_recon[jdx] * V2inv[Mod(idx + power(2, level - 1) * jdx + Length, Length)]);
                sum = sum + (hcoeff_recon[jdx] * W2inv[Mod(idx + power(2, level - 1) * jdx + Length, Length)]);
            End;
            If level = 1 then Begin
                sum = sum + (gcoeff_recon[jdx] * V1inv[Mod(idx + power(2, level - 1) * jdx + Length, Length)]);
                sum = sum + (hcoeff_recon[jdx] * W1inv[Mod(idx + power(2, level - 1) * jdx + Length, Length)]);
            End;
        End;
        ReconstructedSignal[idx] = ReconstructedSignal[idx] + sum;
    End;
End;


// Graficar la salida del filtro pasa bajo
Plot1(ReconstructedSignal[0], "Reconstructed Signal");

